# Yii fetching records by type

Tags: php, yii, grouping, processing-efficiency

I'm wondering if Yii has an efficient method for grouping items by type.

Let's say I have the following model:

```
Tag
------
id
name    
type_id
```

And let's say there are 5 different types of `Tag`s. I want to be able to display in my index all tags in sections by `type_id`. Is there a Yii-way of accomplishing this?

Outside a framework I would write a function such that results fetched from the DB were stored like this:

```
$tags[$typeID][] = $tag;
```

Then in each section I could do something like:

```
foreach( $tags[$typeID] as $tag )
{
    // Here are all tags for one $typeID
}
```

But I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do this in Yii without:

A) looping through the entire result set first and rewriting it or,

B) running 5 different queries.

Answer (score 2):

When using ActiveRecord simply specify the "index" in the DBCriteria. So in a query do:

```
ActiveRecordClass::model()->findAll(array('index'=>'type_id'));
```

That will return an assoc array that your after. TBF it probably executes exactly the same code, but this is obviously easier to use that performing it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your active record class is called `MyActiveRecordClass`, the simplest approach should be sufficient:

```
$models = MyActiveRecordClass::model()->findAll();
$groupedModels = array();

foreach ($models as $model) {
    $groupedModels[$model->typeID][] = $model;
}
```

If you give more specific information about how you intend to display the grouped results it might be that a better approach can be worked out.